# Akka Stream continuously consume websocket

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka, streaming, akka-stream

Im kinda new to Scala and Akka Stream and im trying to get JSON String messages from a websocket and push them to a Kafka topic.

For now i am only working on the "get messages from a ws" part.

Messages coming from the websocket looks like this :

```
{  
   "bitcoin":"6389.06534240",
   "ethereum":"192.93111286",
   "monero":"108.90302506",
   "litecoin":"52.25484165"
}
```

I want to split this JSON message to multiple messages :

```
   {"coin": "bitcoin", "price": "6389.06534240"}
   {"coin": "ethereum", "price": "192.93111286"}
   {"coin": "monero", "price": "108.90302506"}
   {"coin": "litecoin", "price": "52.25484165"}
```

And then push each of these messages to a kafka topic.

Here's what i achieved so far :

```
val message_decomposition: Flow[Message, String, NotUsed] = Flow[Message].mapConcat(
    msg => msg.toString.replaceAll("[{})(]", "").split(",")
  ).map( msg => {
    val splitted = msg.split(":")
    s"{'coin': ${splitted(0)}, 'price': ${splitted(1)}}"
  })

val sink: Sink[String, Future[Done]] = Sink.foreach[String](println)

val flow: Flow[Message, Message, Promise[Option[Message]]] =
    Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat(
      message_decomposition.to(sink),
      Source.maybe[Message])(Keep.right)

val (upgradeResponse, promise) = Http().singleWebSocketRequest(
      WebSocketRequest("wss://ws.coincap.io/prices?assets=ALL"),
      flow)
```

It's working im getting the expected output Json message but i was wondering if i could write this producer in a more "Akka-ish" style, like using GraphDSL. So i have a few questions :

- Is it possible to continuously consume a WebSocket using a GraphDSL ? If yes, can you show me a example please ?
- Is it a good idea to consume the WS using a GraphDSL ?
- Should i decompose the received Json Message like im doing before sending it to kafka ? Or it's better to send it as it is for lower latency ?
- After producing the message to Kafka, i am planning to consume it using Apache Storm, is it a good idea ? Or should i stick with Akka ?

Thanks for reading me, Regards,
Arès

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is plenty Akka-ish: `scaladsl` is just as Akka as the `GraphDSL` or implementing a custom `GraphStage`.  The only reason, IMO/E, to go to the `GraphDSL` is if the actual shape of the graph isn't readily expressible in the `scaladsl`.

I would personally go the route of defining a `CoinPrice` class to make the model explicit

```scala
case class CoinPrice(coin: String, price: BigDecimal)
```

And then have a `Flow[Message, CoinPrice, NotUsed]` which parses 1 incoming message into zero or more `CoinPrice`s.  Something (using Play JSON here) like:

```scala
val toCoinPrices =
  Flow[Message]
    .mapConcat { msg =>
      Json.parse(msg.toString)
        .asOpt[JsObject]
        .toList
        .flatMap { json =>
          json.underlying.flatMap { kv =>
            import scala.util.Try

            kv match {
              case (coin, JsString(priceStr)) =>
                Try(BigDecimal(priceStr)).toOption
                  .map(p => CoinPrice(coin, p))                

              case (coin, JsNumber(price)) => Some(CoinPrice(coin, price))
              case _ => None
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

You might, depending on what the size of the JSONs in the message are, want to break that into different stream stages to allow for an async boundary between the JSON parse and the extraction into `CoinPrice`s.  For example,

```scala
Flow[Message]
  .mapConcat { msg =>
    Json.parse(msg.toString).asOpt[JsObject].toList
  }
  .async
  .mapConcat { json =>
    json.underlying.flatMap { kv =>
      import scala.util.Try

      kv match {
        case (coin, JsString(priceStr)) =>
          Try(BigDecimal(priceStr)).toOption
            .map(p => CoinPrice(coin, p))

        case (coin, JsNumber(price)) => Some(CoinPrice(coin, price))
        case _ => None
      }
    }
  }
```

In the above, the stages on either side of the `async` boundary will execute in separate actors and thus, possibly concurrently (if there's enough CPU cores available etc.), at the cost of extra overhead for the actors to coordinate and exchange messages.  That extra coordination/communication overhead (cf. Gunther's Universal Scalability Law) is only going to be worth it if the JSON objects are sufficiently large and coming in sufficiently quickly (consistently coming in before the previous one has finished processing).

If your intention is to consume the websocket until the program stops, you might find it clearer to just use `Source.never[Message]`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it's very clear, i just have one question tho. How can i break my response into different stream stages ?  Can you just show me a little example please ? Or orient me to the proper part of the documentation ?